# Can we have more than one Variadic parameter in swift functions?

Tags: ios, swift, func, variadic

According to Apple:
"A function can have multiple variadic parameters. The first parameter that comes after a variadic parameter must have an argument label."

But when I tried doing the same it is giving me following error.
"Only a single variadic parameter '...' is permitted"
Please see the attached screenshot

[image]

**Correction:**
Actually I was using the older version of XCode which doesn't support Multiple Variadic Parameters.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: What happens if you keep the label on the first parameter? And what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: i can't find any issue here.

Answer (score 5):

[Multiple variadic parameters was only released in Swift 5.4](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/variadic-parameters/), which comes with Xcode 12.5.

If you are using an older Swift/Xcode version, you need to update to be able to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple variadic parameters was only released in Swift 5.4, or later version

```
 func goalsOfPlayer(times: Int..., players: String...) {
        for i in times {
            print("times \(i)")
        }
      for j in players {
        print("players \(j)")
      }
    
    }
    
goalsOfPlayer(times: 18, 33, 55, 90, players: "Dani", "Jamie", "Roy")
```